# Ошибка в условном операторе: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' "

Tags: php

Почему программа

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    error_reporting (E_ALL);
    $x = $x ?: 1;
    echo $x;
    ?>
    </body>
```

выводит ошибку

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in G:\Server\domains\mysite\www\index.php on line 10

Хотя должна выводить только предупреждение о том, что переменная х не определена?

Answer (score 4):

```
$x = $x ?: 1;
```

Неправильный тренарный оператор после знака ? должен идти условие если true, а только потом : и условие если false
Например вот так

```
$x = (1==1)?1:$x;
```

Comment: это из учебника пример, там написано, что средний параметр условного оператора допускается не указывать. у меня на локальном сервере версия пхп 5.2.17, может, для того, чтобы это срабатывало, нужна  более старшая версия.

Comment: @Heidel, возможно. У меня стоит 5.4.3 работает и показывает Notice

Comment: да, видимо, так и есть.